# Number of changes occurred across variables

Tags: stata

I have variables like `var2000`, `var2001`, `var2002` meaning that each are variables for year `2000`, `2001`, `2002`, respectively.

I want to count the number of times they changed from previous year to next year.

So my purpose is to construct `Num_change` like this:

```
var2000 var2001 var2002 Num_change
   3      2       1        2
   4      4       4        0
   1      0       0        1
   1      0       1        2
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
replace Num_change=2 if var2000~=var2001 & var2001~=var2002
```

However, this method is too tedious when there are many years.

Is there any simple short way to do this?

Comment: As @PearlySpencer hinted, your code isn't complete without showing how you got the 0 and 1 values for your new variable. I can easily guess, but the point is that code examples should be complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
clear

input var2000 var2001 var2002 
   3      2       1       
   4      4       4       
   1      0       0       
   1      0       1       
end

generate id = _n
reshape long var, i(id)

bysort id (_j): generate tag = var != var[_n-1]
reshape wide var tag, i(id)

egen Num_change = rowtotal(tag*)
replace Num_change = Num_change - 1
drop id tag*

list, abbreviate(10)

     +------------------------------------------+
     | var2000   var2001   var2002   Num_change |
     |------------------------------------------|
  1. |       3         2         1            2 |
  2. |       4         4         4            0 |
  3. |       1         0         0            1 |
  4. |       1         0         1            2 |
     +------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Note that you can also do the same thing with loops.

Comment: Thank you. But it seems `reshape` and `bysort` takes an enormous amount of time when the data is huge. But I am not an expert. Do you think it's as fast as the crude rough way I wrote?

Comment: It all depends. I answered based on your toy example. With huge datasets loops will also be slow.

Comment: By the way, your approach does not calculate anything so by definition is not comparable.

Answer (score 2):

@Pearly Spencer focused reasonably on the question you had, how to get a particular variable. I would go further and suggest that you should `reshape long` and not `reshape` back. Your data looks like panel or longitudinal data and are best left `long`. Your problem is characteristic: even simple questions often require awkward answers with a wide layout (structure, format) for long data. There are exceptions to that, principally that someone has written an `egen` function to do something rowwise. For a longer discussion, see [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046).

The rest of my answer shows two ways of getting what you want from your existing layout with loops. For your real data, with many variables it won't be essential to type out all the names of the variables: there will be other ways to do it, but how best to do it depends on your real names, which you don't tell us.

```
clear 
input var2000 var2001 var2002 Num_change
   3      2       1        2
   4      4       4        0
   1      0       0        1
   1      0       1        2
 end 

 * 1 
 local vars var2000 var2001 var2002 
 gettoken first vars : vars 
 gen wanted = 0 

 quietly while "`vars'" != "" { 
    gettoken next vars : vars
    replace wanted = wanted + (`next' != `first') 
    local first `next' 
} 

* 2 
local vars var2000 var2001 var2002 
gen WANTED = 0 
tokenize `vars' 
local nvars : word count `vars' 

quietly forval j = 2/`nvars' { 
    local i = `j' - 1 
    replace WANTED = WANTED + (``j'' !=  ``i'') 
}

list 

     +----------------------------------------------------------+
     | var2000   var2001   var2002   Num_ch~e   wanted   WANTED |
     |----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |       3         2         1          2        2        2 |
  2. |       4         4         4          0        0        0 |
  3. |       1         0         0          1        1        1 |
  4. |       1         0         1          2        2        2 |
     +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I agree about long form and this is the reason i opted for `reshape`.